# completing read CRUD sql in jsp servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I asked this questions last night, and was kind of foolish not to ask how to complete the coding on it.  I now have a dropdown box in a JSP populated with some data from an SQL database.  I am trying to get the selected data to direct to the final viewing page, but again am running into some difficulty with this.

When I run the program, it either populates the page with all the data from the list database, or will give me an unfriendly error.

My current coding is as such:

the Bean:

```
package com.login.read;

public class ReadBean {

protected int id;
protected String title;
protected String author;
protected String text;


public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(int newID){
    id = newID;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String newTitle){
    title = newTitle;
}

public String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }

public void setAuthor(String newAuthor){
    author = newAuthor;
}

public String getText(){       
        return text;
    } 


public void setText(String newText){
    text = newText;
}

}
```

The Controller:

```
package com.login.read;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet (urlPatterns={"/com/defaultValidate/ReadController"})
public class ReadController extends HttpServlet {




protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String address;
    List<ReadBean> myList = new ArrayList<ReadBean>();

    if(request.getParameter("ReadConfirm") != null){  
        try {
            Connection connect = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM prayers ORDER BY prayerTitle DESC";
            PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(SQL);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                ReadBean reader = new ReadBean();
                reader.setTitle(rs.getString("prayerTitle"));
                reader.setAuthor(rs.getString("author"));
                reader.setText(rs.getString("text"));
                myList.add(reader);   
            }

            request.getSession().setAttribute("ref", myList);


            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            connect.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        address = "ReadConfirm.jsp";
    } else if(request.getParameter("ReadView") != null){ 

        address = "ReadView.jsp";
    } else{
        address = null;
    }

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

}
}
```

And my jsp pages that link the drop-down box to the selected material:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

%@include file="MenuHeader.jsp"%>
</div>
    <div id="mainBorder"> </div>
        <div id="mainBody">
            <table id="mainTable">
                <tr>
                    <td id="sidebar">
                        <h2>Options</h2>  
                            <ul>

            </ul>
        </td>
        <td id="mainContent">
                        <h2 id="contentHeader">Select a prayer</h2>

                        <form action="ReadController">
                            <table border="1" width="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><select name="prayer_id">

                                                <c:forEach var="view" items="${ref}">
                            <h2>${view.title}</h2>

                            <h3>${view.author}</h3>

                            <p>${view.text}</p>
                        </c:forEach>

                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="submit" name="ReadView"     value="View">    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </form>
    <td id="imageBar">

            </td>   
        </table>
    <%@ include file="../menuHeaderAndFooter/MenuFooter.jsp" %>
```

and the final viewing page:

```
 <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
%@include file="MenuHeader.jsp"%>
</div>
    <div id="mainBorder"> </div>
        <div id="mainBody">
            <table id="mainTable">
                <tr>
                    <td id="sidebar">
                        <h2>Options</h2>  
                            <ul>

            </ul>
        </td>
        <td id="mainContent">


                        <c:forEach var="view" items="${res}">
                            <h2>${view.title}</h2>

                            <h3>${view.author}</h3>

                            <p>${view.text}</p>
                        </c:forEach>




                        <form action="../Read.jsp">
                            <p>Click on the return button to return to the main menu</p>
                            <input type="submit" name="return" value="Return">
                        </form>

    <td id="imageBar">

            </td>   
        </table>
    <%@ include file="../menuHeaderAndFooter/MenuFooter.jsp" %>
```

As always, any and all assistance in this regard is incredibly helpful.  I am a relative newbie to the world of jsp and servlets.

If one needs any reference as to the continuation of this sequence, kindly view the previous question I posted regarding dynamically displaying data in a jsp combo-box.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: First of all tell us that what error you are getting? Post an error log as well.

Answer (score 0):

By reading above code, I can just ask you that where you have stored your session attribute in **variable "var"**, which is being used in `c:foreach` loop ?

Comment: @Sotirios & Ravi:  As of of the code the way I have displayed it, there currently is no error but all the elements of the database are displayed as opposed to the desired effect of displaying the selecting data from the drop-down box.  I've tried playing with the program on both the controller and the JSP.  But, as you can see, I am currently getting all the data displayed regardless of what section of the box I select.